# Enable IntelliJ hotswap of html and javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, css, intellij-idea, hotswap

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and I'm using it to develop an AngularJS / Java web application. When I make changes to HTML or JavaScript code, I always have to restart the app server (I'm using Jetty). Is there a config or plugin that provides hotswap for HTML/JS/CSS files?

I'm using IntelliJ 12 Ultimate edition.

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-applications-running-on-application-servers.html .

Comment: @CrazyCoder: your link is broken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the option "Update resources". You should be able find this option in your server Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: The problem is that when I modify an HTML/JS/CSS file, nothing is getting triggered in IntelliJ to do anything. I think IntelliJ watches for changes to Java code but not to resources.

Comment: I was able to get it working by setting Run/Debug configuration --> "On frame deactivation" to "Update classes and resources". At first I had tried setting the "On 'Update' action" but that event was not getting fired after modifying a resource.

Comment: "On 'Update' action" means what should happen when you hit Update button. This button is in your tab with running applications.

Comment: Ah, okay. I also discovered that the "Update classes and resources" options are only available when the deployment option is an "exploded" war.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem but I already fixed it. You can follow this steps:

1. Go to Help->Find Action
2. Type "Registry".
3. Find and mark : “compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running”.
4. Close the Dialog.
5. Go to "Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler".
6. Mark "Build project automatically".
7. Apply changes.
8. Go to Spring Boot Configuration and if everything goes well it will display a warning about "background compilation", Run your Spring Boot Application and you should be able to see your statisc's files changes when refresh your browser.

Hope it helps.

Comment: (y) Great that it helped you! @Monir

Comment: @RafaelReyes Thanks a lot, it works. But why it's not default option and why there is **red** warning like error on spring boot configuration? **Is there any drawbacks of this solution**.

Comment: As a note, "Settings" on a Mac is _Preferences_

Comment: Helped for me.
Also check this: http://garywaddell.com/2015/11/20/spring-boot-intellij-idea-not-reloading-static-content/

(As JeanValjean stated, yes on a mac it is different "Settings" is "Preferences")

Comment: Saved me. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelReyes awesome, super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As i found this thread interesting, i also found a lot of explanations here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html

Answer (score 1):

Also, a keyboard shortcut(e.g. Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+F5) to "**Run -> Reload changed classes**" might come handy. It helps me to save changes multiple times and then restart the server when I'm done (unless using JRebel :)

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, which might not be obvious - to activate the automatic build you have to activate the IntelliJ window. It is still very convenient, although you have to switch windows when operation only in the browser.