# Intellij Build > Recomplie on html files Grayed out

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**OS**: Windows 10

**Intellij**:  2016.3.2

**Java**: 1.7

I have a basic **Springboot** project using **Thymeleaf** as the templating engine. When I make a change to a Java file I can use menu option *Build > Recompile* (*Ctrl + Shift + F9*) to recompile.

This option is not available for *.html files. (Note: this used to work).

I am using an embedded tomcat as part of Spring.

Any idea as to why this option is now grayed out?

Assuming it must be a setting thing but I simply couldn't find anything on the web but I did read something about "Update classes and resources" options are only available when the deployment option is an "exploded" war.

Comment: Just found out this. In version 2016.2 *recompile* for Thymeleaf templates was available. Alternative option will be *Build → Rebuild Project*.

Comment: @DimaSan Build > Rebuild Project is certainly an option but this builds the entire project. Surely there must be a way just to build a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling thymeleaf files is possible by **Ctrl + Shift + F9**. What worked for me was to rebuild the project from scratch hence indicating some sort of project setting causing this issue.

Looking at .idea/compiler.xml I can see the old file contained:

```
<wildcardResourcePatterns>
      <entry name="!?*.java" />
      <entry name="!?*.class" />
      <entry name="!?*.groovy" />
      <entry name="!?*.scala" />
      <entry name="!?*.flex" />
      <entry name="!?*.kt" />
      <entry name="!?*.clj" />
      <entry name="!?*.aj" />
</wildcardResourcePatterns>
```

which may be the have caused this issue in conjunction with something else.

Comment: Another alternative is to look at this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43234019/1512175

Comment: This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895730/spring-boot-devtools-static-content-reloading-does-not-work-in-intellij/35895848