# How to enable hot-swap of HMTL and javascript files in IntelliJ Community edition?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, spring-boot, intellij-idea, npm

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and I'm using it to develop an AngularJS application having spring-boot as the backend server. When I make any changes to HTML or JavaScript code, I always have to restart the app server. Is there a config or plugin that provides hot-swap for HTML/JS/CSS files?

I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 2017.2.17, Angular 1.4.4, Node 4.2.1 and NPM 2.14.7.

Comment: try webpack https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: Tried already. It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i'm not wrong, You should try to use Intellij Ultimate, and after that, read the @Rafael Reyes answer, it seems to be good!
Link -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43234019/5240348

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such functionality in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I solved this problem using external tool for example https://browsersync.io which can be operated from inside idea.