# InteliJ idea, disable auto build for java, not HTML

Tags: intellij-idea

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43234019/11369236

I did those and now, when I remove a line of Java code, it automatically restarts debug.

But I do not want this.

When I change HTML, I have to refresh browser also (it does not restart ide, no need of course but I do not want to refresh tab). It does not refresh automatically. But this is not a big problem.

It only should restart HTML (or I can manually restart it) but not for Java or backend files. I could not see such an option.

When I disable "build automatically" (I use the latest version), I have to restart ide to see HTML changes on the browser.

I can not find a way out.

Comment: You should provide more details about your project configuration, how the artifact is configured, what are the Update settings, what app server is used, do you run with JS debugger or not, etc. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful as well. Feel free to [contact support directly](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) as it would be easier to communicate and share the files via the support ticket.

Comment: It is basic spring project with HTML files which has js part in it. Embedded spring tomcat is used
They replied 
ntelliJ IDEA build is incremental, it updates only the changed and dependent files. You can't partially disable it, only by completely excluding the files/folders from the build.